# Bazel - BUILD not referencing external dependency

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-gazelle, gazelle

I'm trying to run some grpc tests with bazel.
I'm using `"google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"` to dial insecurely.

When running `bazel test ...`, I get the following error:

```
no such package '@org_golang_google_grpc//credentials/insecure': BUILD file not found in directory 'credentials/insecure' of external repository @org_golang_google_grpc. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//go/internal/handlers/helloworld:helloworld_test'
```

I am generating my BUILD files with gazelle which outputs this for the go_test

```
go_test(
    name = "helloworld_test",
    srcs = ["helloworld_test.go"],
    deps = [
        ":helloworld",
        "//protos/helloworld",
        "@com_github_stretchr_testify//assert",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//:go_default_library",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//credentials/insecure",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//test/bufconn",
        "@org_uber_go_zap//:zap",
        "@org_uber_go_zap//zaptest",
    ],
)
```

My go.mod file contains the dep:
`google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0`

My deps.bzl is auto generated by gazelle:

```
go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_google_grpc",
    importpath = "google.golang.org/grpc",
    sum = "h1:9n77onPX5F3qfFCqjy9dhn8PbNQsIKeVU04J9G7umt8=",
    version = "v1.47.0",
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Was a BUILD file generated in the directory containing the `insecure` package? This directory  would be something of the form `google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WORKSPACE, the local go_repositories() generated by gazelle must be called before gazelle_dependencies(), which will
define an ancient version of org_golang_google_grpc if it doesn't
exist yet and the local go_repository for the newer version will be
silently ignored. [Reference](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/1233#issuecomment-1094334092)